# Can files compressed with bzip2 be relied upon to be deterministic (reproducible)?

Tags: checksum, bzip2, reproducible-build

I am trying to determine if there are any potential issues using `bzip2` to compress files that need to be 100% reproducible.  Specifically: can metadata (name / inode, lastmod date, etc) or anything else cause identical file contents to **produce a different checksum** on the resulting `.bz2` archive?

As an example, [gzip is not by default deterministic](https://medium.com/@mpreziuso/is-gzip-deterministic-26c81bfd0a49) unless `-n` is used.

My crude tests so far suggest that bzip2 does indeed consistently produce identical files given identical input data (regardless of metadata, platform, filesystem, etc), but it would be nice to have more than anecdotal evidence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bzip2` files only contain [basic format signatures, compressed data and the information needed to decompress that data](https://github.com/dsnet/compress/blob/master/doc/bzip2-format.pdf). They don’t contain any file-specific meta-data; instead, they rely on the compressed file’s metadata (thus `file.bz2` is uncompressed to `file`, with the timestamps of `file.bz2`, regardless of the original file name and original timestamps).

There is one part of the compression that can vary, the input randomisation; but that has been disabled in practice for a long time, and current versions of `bzip2` don’t randomise their input.

As a result, the output of `bzip2` only depends on the input data and the compression level. The output is deterministic.

I’m not sure you’ll find an authoritative source for all this; the best evidence I can offer is the absence of any mention of `bzip2` in the [Debian reproducible builds notes](https://wiki.debian.org/ReproducibleBuilds/Howto). `bzip2` is used in Debian, so if it did cause issues it would get a mention, in the same way [`gzip` does](https://wiki.debian.org/ReproducibleBuilds/TimestampsInGzipHeaders).